# How do I do a "for each" , starting at a certain index of a list (Python)?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have this list:

```
thelist = ['apple','orange','banana','grapes']
for fruit in thelist:
```

This would go through all the fruits.

However, what if I wanted to start at orange? Instead of starting at apple?
Sure, I could do "if ...continue", but there must be a better way?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm dumb, haha. I guess it's too late at night to think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using python's elegant [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation#answer-509295)

```
>>> for fruit in thelist[1:]:
>>>    print fruit
```

Answer (score 14):

```
for fruit in thelist[1:]:
    ...
```

this of course suppose you know at which index to start. but you can find the index easily:

```
for fruit in thelist[thelist.index('orange'):]:
    ...
```

Comment: btw. you might want to call .index on "thelist" instead of "fruit" :)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Paul McGuire, slicing a list creates a copy in memory of the result.  If you have a list with 500,000 elements then doing `l[2:]` is going to create a new 499,998 element list.

To avoid this, use `itertools.islice`:

```
>>> thelist = ['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> import itertools

>>> for i in itertools.islice(thelist, 1, None):
...     print i
...
b
c
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for fruit in thelist [1:]:
```

will start at the second element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
for fruit in thelist[1:]:
    print fruit
```

Comment: fixed, yet it was just for the concept

Answer (score 0):

Slices make copies of lists, so if there are *many* items, or if you don't want to separately search the list for the starting index, an iterator will let you search, and then continue from there:

```
>>> thelist = ['apple','orange','banana','grapes']
>>> fruit_iter = iter(thelist)
>>> target_value = 'orange'
>>> while fruit_iter.next() != target_value: pass
...
>>> # at this point, fruit_iter points to the entry after target_value
>>> print ','.join(fruit_iter)
banana,grapes
>>>
```